# isotope cssHooks overwrite jQuery.transit cssHooks

Tags: firefox, jquery-plugins, css-transitions, jquery-isotope

I have a strange issue where, I can not find any simple solution. Using the `isotope` Plugin and the `jQuery.transit` Plugin in the same document, makes some of the `jQuery.transit` plugin supported css3 transitions become unusable (only in FF16).

It looks like the `$.cssHooks` function in isotope breaks the `cssHooks` functions from other plugins.

If i disable in isotope.js the line 216

```
setIsoTransform( elem, 'scale', value );
```

in this function:

```
$.cssHooks.scale = {
  set: function( elem, value ) {
    // uncomment this bit if you want to properly parse strings
    // if ( typeof value === 'string' ) {
    //   value = parseFloat( value );
    // }
   // alert(elem+"  "+value)
    setIsoTransform( elem, 'scale', value );
  },
  get: function( elem, computed ) {
    var transform = $.data( elem, 'isoTransform' );
    return transform && transform.scale ? transform.scale : 1;
  }
};
```

than the `cssHooks` function from jQuery transit works well. (In this case the scale function from Isotope does not work any more.)

I don't understand why isotope extend the `cssHooks` this way, and why this influence any other object on the page, and not just the elements which should be managed via isotope.

I hope you can give me a good direction, or some update.

Cheers,

ThemePunch